# Window Object in html and javascript integration

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Very simple question but is's hard for me..:(
Seeing Facebook integration, whatever you loggin with Facebook account to a site, it automatically pops up a windows with Facebook URL and you can provide u/p to facebook).

My question is how javascript in site does receive the login result from Facebook ..??. It's mean I wanna understand how opened windows communicate with main document and how javascript in both interact. Could someone let me know the relation and mechanism of window object with inner javascript in site..

Best regard

Comment: Lookup oauth2 and Facebook. https://www.google.com/search?q=oauth2+facebook the exact mechanism of how the response is received is explained in the oauth protocol

Comment: This javascript code has been minified and I couldn't help me understand anything at all... :(

Comment: what do you mean? I wasn't suggesting you look at the source on that site, rather read the background information on the oauth2 technology, which would serve to give you some insight into how it works.

Comment: Thank... I understand about jwt, cryptography,oauth2 methodologies.. etc..Just thing I wander about the communication between windows object with it's opener and javascript inside..This document didn't mention about that..